# How to rewrite an url via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the following URL via .htaccess:

```
http://website.com/dealer_home.php?id=dealer1
```

The result I am aiming for is this, where `dealer1` is the username which is set as variable:

```
http://website.com/dealer1
```

I have tried this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /dealer_home.php?id=$1 [L]
```

However I get "Internal Server Error" message when trying to load any of the website pages.

Can you provide some advice where I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I tried also `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dealer_home.php?id=$1 [PT]` but no success.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a conflict with existing files/folders and root uri.
Try this code instead

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /dealer_home.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This rule will match every url like `domain.com/something` if `something` is not an existing file or folder.
So if you have other rules then you should put them above this one.

---

EDIT: to avoid duplicate content and to redirect old format to new url format

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/dealer_home\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /dealer_home.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think you are on the right way since now the pages are loading ok. The problem is that the URL is not being changed.

Comment: This rule now allows you to use `http://website.com/dealer1` but it does not redirect `http://website.com/dealer_home.php?id=dealer1` to new url format. Is it what you want ?

Comment: Ahhh so stupid, I did forget to change the URL redirect. Thank you, now all works great!

Comment: Glad it worked. Anyway, i added an "edit" part in my answer if you want to redirect old format to new url format